# Erro ao tentar chamar outra ViewController por botão [IOS 13]

Tags: ios, swift

Estou estudando sobre Clean-Swift e arquitetura VIP, e estou tendo dificuldades em fazer a parte de rotas para chamar uma ViewController pelo o botão. Pode parecer uma coisa simples, porem não tenho muita experiencia com Swift.
Não estou utilizando StoryBoard, e sim Xib file 
Se alguém puder me ajudar e explicar onde posso estar errando agradeço!

HomeViewController

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController
{

  var routerPassData = FistRouter()

  override func viewDidLoad()
 {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.view.backgroundColor = .blue
   let newBtn = UIButton()
       newBtn.setTitle("btn", for: .normal)
       newBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin", 
       size: 50)
       newBtn.addTarget(routerPassData.self, action: #selector(routerPassData.teste), for: .touchUpInside)
       newBtn.frame =  CGRect(x: 15, y: 54, width: 300, height: 500)
       newBtn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
       self.view.addSubview(newBtn)
   }

 }
```

HomeRouter

```
class HomeRouter: NSObject
{

 @objc func teste() {
 let pass = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("secView", owner: self, options: 
 nil)?.first as? secViewController
 pass?.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Quando eu coloco esse Func de teste na ViewController tenho o resultado esperado que é chamar a outra ViewController, só que quando eu separo isso me da esse erro

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
```

Onde eu posso estar errando?

Answer (score 1):

Olá vi alguns erros no seu código você está usando o viewDidLoad para chamar outra tela é não é bem assim que funciona veja meu código:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var newBtn: UIButton = {
        var btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("btn", for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin", size: 50)
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 54, width: 300, height: 500)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(chamarOutraView), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        return btn
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(newBtn)
    }


    @objc func chamarOutraView(){
        // Primeiro você precisa registrar sua ViewController antes de chamar
        let newViewController = SegundaViewController(nibName: "SegundaViewController", bundle: nil)
        // Se desejar que a view fique em fullScreen adicione a linha a baixo
        newViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        // E sempra para chamarmos outra view nao devemos usar o metodo viewDidLoad
        // E sim o present que é responsavel para chamar outra ViewController
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Depois crie sua próxima ViewController a principio ela não precisa ter nada:

```
class SegundaViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado. Se estiver começando um projeto agora eu lhe indico ver um pouco sobre como fazer tela programaticamente na minha opinião é muito melhor que NIB(XIB) e Storyboard.